# What is the genre / style of this song and songs like it? Short Piano Notes on every beat in background

Tags: identify-this-genre, piano, style

What is the genre / style of this song and songs like it such as Mr Blue Sky? Short Piano Notes on every beat in background. Also is there a name to it? And are there any other songs in a similar style? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V-EmRSQ_pc

(Edit)
Full Song Link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1_LUcmtWqA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In it's broadest sense, the term for this kind of repetitive accompaniment is *ostinato*: a repeated bass figure over which a melody occurs. Ostinato, however, can refer to a whole repeated sequence of notes or chords; it need not be a single chord.

Stylistically, the songs you're asking about have their roots in traditional New Orleans jazz. For example, listen to the guitar and drums in [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHE7I1MWbrc). It's often called "four on the floor", which is a reference to a kick drum (bass drum) being played on all four beats of a measure, or more generally to the rhythm section as a whole.

[Doctor John](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMDPZUvuI4Q) often uses this style, or variations on it, as does [Randy Newman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G55cJrUs9VM).

But short, repeated chords on each beat can show up in other styles. For example, Bohemian Rhapsody, "[I see a little silhouette of a man...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ&t=3m05s)", owes more to classical music than jazz.

Answer (score 1):

One classic use of this style of piano is on ["A Day in the Life"](https://youtu.be/usNsCeOV4GM?t=136) by the Beatles from the "Sgt. Pepper" album. The link is to the part where that piano riff starts, but it's worth listening from the beginning.

Comment: Here is the link to the full song  just found. I'm looking for more of an upbeat type of song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1_LUcmtWqA

Answer (score 1):

As PiedPiper noted, you tend to hear a version of this style frequently in Beatles' songs, such as ["Hey Jude"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_MjCqQoLLA), ["Penny Lane"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfxQ1oDiEJM) and ["Lady Madonna"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLRiGX3L-kw).

A great non-Beatles example of this style with more of the uptempo mood you're looking for would be "5th Beatle" Billy Preston's ["Nothing from Nothing"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HqyEHqEYho). It's certainly a distinctive sound, although I'm hard pressed to give it a name. It's also here in the work of another Beatles-adjacent artist, Jeff Lynne's ["Mr Blue Sky"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQUlA8Hcv4s).

It's basically 60s/70s piano rock, with the piano used as a rhythm instrument. You might call it "chords piano" or "rhythm piano" but neither of those is much good to search on. Your sample song puts me a quite a bit in mind of 70s Broadway, but I can't find a good example except maybe ["Hard Knock Life"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0bOH8ABpco) from Annie.

A different rhythm, but a similar feel and mood is Supergrass's 90s retro slacker anthem, [Alright](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUE4oDunYkc).